# Binding an async function with decorators using babel

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs

I'm trying to bind an async function inside of a React class. Previous I have been doing so like this using co

```
import React from 'react';
import { bind } from 'lodash';
import { wrap } from 'co';
import ajax from 'qajax';

export default class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleSubmit = bind(wrap(this.handleSubmit), this);
    }

    *handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const Data = { foo: this.state.foo };

        const Result = yield ajax({ /* ... */ data: Data })

        //...
    }
}
```

which works fine.

I'm trying to refactor it to use decorators and async functions provided by babel to make the code cleaner, like so

```
import React from 'react';
import { bind } from 'lodash';
import { wrap } from 'co';
import ajax from 'qajax';

function AutoBind(target, name, descriptor) {
    let fn = descriptor.value;

    delete descriptor.value;
    delete descriptor.writable;

    descriptor.get = function() {
        return function () { fn.apply(this, arguments); }
    }
}

export default class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    @AutoBind
    async handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const Data = { foo: this.state.foo };

        const Result = await ajax({ /* ... */ data: Data })

        //...
    }
}
```

The problem with the latter is that the this reference inside teh handleSubmit function is set to the Window object, presumable  due to the compiled output binding the _asyncToGenerator function rather than the generator callback function provided. The compiled output snippet is as follows

```
_createDecoratedClass(Foo, [{
        key: 'handleSubmit',
        decorators: [AutoBind],
        value: _asyncToGenerator(function* (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            //...
        })
    }
```

I know this is pretty new territory and issues like this are to be expected, I was just wondering if anyone has tried something similar and found a solution, for the time being I'm going to stick with the previous working method.

Finally, the AutoBind decorator works as expected on non async functions, like this

```
@AutoBind
handleScreennameChange({ target: { value }}) {
    this.setState({
        screen_name: value
    });
}
```

Comment: Wait, why don't you make that getter just `function(){ return fn; }`? And why do you use a getter at all?

Comment: I adapted the example from http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/03/31/5.0.0/ - though I probably didn't need to

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was simply my autobind decorator that wasn't working as intended.

I solved the problem using https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator rather than rolling my own autobind